# Routes used in default routers provided by ISP's

Tags: networking, router

I would like to know if the default routers that the ISP's provide come hardcoded with default path or is it something that come via "updates".

What I really would like was to buy a better router to my home but the question pops up: `How does the new router will know what is the default gateway?`

I don't have much knowledge about WAN's. I really would like some answer giving an insight how the default router from the ISP knows which path it has to take.

Comment: When the router is first plugged to the internet connection it negotiates with the next upstream device (at the ISP). That device becomes the routers default gateway, and has all the routing information required.

Comment: @DavidPostill How does the ISP knows I "paid the bill"?

Comment: If you don't pay the bill your line will be disconnected - exactly the same way a landline telephone works. The ISP (or telephone company) can flip a switch (electronically) to disconnect you.

Comment: If you plug a modem/router into a incoming line that is not enabled, then the initial negotiation will fail and modem/router lights will show no internet connection.

Comment: See [How does a DSL modem know which ISP to connect to?](http://superuser.com/q/582211) for more information.

Comment: Note that with some types of connections (eg [PPPoE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-point_protocol_over_Ethernet)) you have to enter authorisation (user name and password) to connect. Other connections (Cable, DSL, ADSL) do require this and auto-negotiate the connection.